# How to wait for the cmd command to get executed before running the next command?

Tags: java

Need to wait for the cmd command to get executed before running the display function.

Need the `Process p` to get executed completely before executing display function.

```
String command1 = "cmd /c start cmd.exe /k \"" + processCommand1 + " && " + processCommand2  +" && "+ exitCommand+"\"";

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);

display();
```

Comment: `p.waitFor()` should work.

Comment: And consider to use ProcessBuilder, not Runtime.exec()!

Answer (score 8):

One way would be to use [`Process.waitFor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--). However in your example you are using `cmd /c start` which will run the actual program asynchronously in the background. You should ensure that the program is started synchronously without `start` so you can wait for it.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use java.lang.ProcessBuilder. JavaDoc had example:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html
Something like that:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("...");
...
Process process = processBuilder.start();
...
int exitCode = process.waitFor();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            output.append(line + "\n");
            if (line.contains(exitConfirm)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    display()
```

this code will either wait for a specific exit line or wait until the process is completed

Comment: What are `exitConfirm` and `output`?